# What is imageMogr2 and what is it used for?

Tags: image-processing, cdn

I see that ImageMogr2 is some kind of tool used by qiniu.com (a chinese hosting provider), If some one could help me understand what it is and what similar tech e have with any other hosting provider available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You may see a very similar service provided by tencent cloud has exactly the same name.
its an image processing utility that can scale, crop, rotate images on-the-fly using URI-programming, which means, defining the image processing command and parameters in the request URIs and you'll get the cropped images based on the original image you uploaded before.

You can easily get their documentations and some simple examples on their website.
e.g. https://developer.qiniu.com/dora/api/1270/the-advanced-treatment-of-images-imagemogr2

but not sure if you can read Chinese.

there are similar solutions provided by a us company. e.g.
https://cloudinary.com/